# Unix command to return all files starting with the word report and except those with log extension

Tags: shell, unix, command

Unix command to return all files starting with the word report and except those with log extension. The result should give output such as report.txt and not report.log files

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for this:

```
$ find . -type f -name report\* ! -name \*.log
```